# TFS - Powershell timeout when calling a unzip function on releasing

Tags: powershell, tfs, unzip

I'm trying to auto deploy from my **Team Foundation Server**(Windows server 2012R2 with PowerShell 4) to my other server(mostly Windows2008R2 with PowerShell 2).

I had written a ps1 file call "TFS_deploy.ps1" that will do some deploy step, and it works as expected both by invoke in TFS and running it by myself(login to server and run).

### Steps of Release

1. Copy files to server
2. Run PowerShell on target machines

### Problems

1. Because there lot of small file, considering performance, I make a **zip** of raw files in Build step, Then insert the **unzip commands** to my "TFS_deploy.ps1", the commands are:

   ```
   function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination){ #Function for unzip 
       $shell = new-object -com shell.application
       $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
       foreach($item in $zip.items())
       {
           $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item,0x14)
       }
   }

   Expand-ZIPFile $zipFile $unzipTo      #call unzip
   ```

   But until now, The step "Run PowerShell on target machines" will get **stuck until timeout, and return nothing**, log looks like:

   ```
   2018-04-19T01:39:15.2320923Z Executing the powershell script: D:\agent\_work\_tasks\PowerShellOnTargetMachines_xxxxxxxxx\1.0.46\PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1
   2018-04-19T01:39:16.4302496Z Deployment started for machine: 'xxxxxxxxx:5985'
   2018-04-19T01:44:29.9661778Z ##[error]Timeout。
   ```

   It only show nothing but timeout after 5 mins.

   BUT, **If I login to server and run "`TFS_deploy.ps1`", Every thing will be OK,
   and PowerShell just done by 1 min or less**.

---

2. I even tried using a python shell to unzip:

   ```
   import zipfile
   path_to_zip_file = ".\\BuildSource.zip"
   directory_to_extract_to = ".\\"
   zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r')
   zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
   zip_ref.close()
   ```

   Than something different happened, the log finally showed something:

   ```
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.5834107Z Deployment status for machine 'XXXXXXXXX:5985' : 'Failed'
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6174186Z ##[error] Failed to execute script unzip"}};]
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6174186Z 
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6174186Z 
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6744240Z ## [error] System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Command execution stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: [3448] Failed to execute script unzip ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Command execution stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: [3448] Failed to execute script unzip
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6744240Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6744240Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6744240Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6744240Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6754297Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6754297Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6754297Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.VSTSPowerShellHost.Main(String[] args)
   2018-04-19T08:18:52.6944268Z ##[error]LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe :return -1。
   ```

---

### Summary

I have trouble with using Powershell to unzip, and it only happens when the ps1 file are invoked by TFS, but no error is occurring if run same ps1 file manually.

Any suggestion on **zip/unzip with TFS**?

### Update 2018/04/23

I had tried to use invoke-command cmdlet to call .ps1 file from my TFS server to target server, **The unzip is success, But when some ps1 file are calling by TFS, it get stuck without showing any result again.**

Here is my cmdlet:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXXXXXXXX -FilePath D:\TFSDeployShareFolder\unzip.ps1 -Credential XXXXXXXXX\autodeploy
```

and unzip.ps1 are:

```
$zipfile = "D:\TFSDeployShareFolder\Officialwebsite.zip"
$unzipDestination = "D:\TFSDeployShareFolder\"

function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination){
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
        foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
        $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item,0x14)
    }
}
Expand-ZIPFile  $zipfile $unzipDestination
```

### Update 2018/5/3 (solution)

I decide to use 7z to make work done,
Simple Google :"powershell unzip with 7z" to find the code, it now works as expected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are settings in TFS to increase the timeout duration. The option may be "hidden" under the advanced properties of the deployment step.

Comment: If you use Powershell on your build agent machine to run the script on the remote machine, how is the result? The command should be like `Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01, Server02 -FilePath c:\Scripts\DiskCollect.ps1`, check this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6

Comment: Hi gvee, I have tried set timeout to 0 (no time out limit), and it will get stuck,I need to kill process manual or it will keep in there event over 10 min.

Hi @CeceDong-MSFT ,Please refer to my update,Thanks !

Comment: Which account do you use to run TFS build? And which account do you use to run the command manually? Are they the same?

Comment: Thanks for reply@CeceDong-MSFT ! I'm using same user as hostname\autodeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-6) Command:

```
$zipfile = "C:\File.zip"
$destination = "C:\Outputpath"
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $zipfile -DestinationPath $destination -Force
```

Comment: I have try this command , it can work nicely on OS AFTER Windows server 2008, 
but it can't run on Windows Server 2008 because .NET Framework version is too old.